# How to know a phone type?

Tags: php, twilio, phone-number, country-codes

I am using the following code to query the type of a phone. I am using php as a language for this project only. I am using the following code.

I am only getting the phone "+12252763867" as output.from the following code

```
$number->phone_number;
```

The question is How do I get the type of the phone?

```
<?php
require "NewServices/Twilio.php";
$AccountSid ="xxx" ;
$AuthToken ="xxxx" ;
$from = '<twilio phone>';
$to = '+12252763867';

$client1 = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$client = new Lookups_Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);


$number = $client->phone_numbers->get("+12252763867");
$body = $number->phone_number;

try
{
  $client1->account->sms_messages->create($from,$to,$body);
} catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {

}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by type of phone? What country are you referring to? What rules apply? In the UK, for instance, a number starting with 07 is a mobile. You must edit your question to include more information before we can help you.

Comment: I want to retrieve the type information country-code etc. from the response to the GET expression The type should tell me whether the phone is a mobile, landline or a fax machine. The country is USA

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Once you have the phone number looked up as you showed here:

```
$number = $client->phone_numbers->get("+12252763867");
$body = $number->phone_number;
```

You can query other fields on that number too, like:

```
$country = $number->country_code
$format  = $number->national_format
```

If you want more information, you can pass the `Type` parameter as "carrier":

```
$number = $client->phone_numbers->get("+12252763867", array("Type" => "carrier"))
```

You can then get the type of number you are asking about.

```
$type = $number->carrier->type
```

Carrier information costs $0.005 per phone number looked up.

Comment: With Twilio's phone verification API, can you determine if a number is attached to an iPhone?

Comment: @bsod No, I'm not aware of any way to determine the device that is attached to a phone number. Notably the device may change over time. What's the reason you want to determine the type of device?

Comment: I'm working on a phone-only mobile app (no tablets, watches, etc.) only for Android and iOS. Part of the policing strategy is to attempt to limit one account per person and plain SMS-OTP verification is just not enough (too easy to get burner numbers). I've looked at TeleSign which has an API that can score phone numbers on how "trusty" they are but the side effect is that it may prevent real people with otherwise fishy numbers from being able to register. If I can require iOS users to SMS-OTP verify from iPhones and Android users from Android phones then I'd be content.

Comment: I think you might want to read the [falsehoods programmers believe about phone numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md) and perhaps rethink your strategy.